# What do the different noise reduction options in Silkypix mean?

Tags: raw, noise, noise-reduction, iso-noise

I'm playing around with RAW files in [Silkypix](http://www.isl.co.jp/SILKYPIX/english/) that came with my Panasonic camera and I am thoroughly confused by the sliders for the noise reduction and the [Silkypix manual isn't of much help](http://www.isl.co.jp/SILKYPIX/english/support/manual/ds4/man0006.html#_Anchor4.7.3) (at least I've a hard time following it).

The options presented as sliders are:

- False Color Control
- Noise Reduction
- Noise Canceller - Noise Level
- Noise Canceller - Noise Cancel

It would be great if someone could relate these options in a concise way and how to use them to good effect.

Comment: "False Color Control" probably mitigates the effect of moiré, a topic which we don't seem to have covered yet on this site. Let's try to fix that... http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moire-how-can-we-avoid-it

Comment: I'm not positive, but I doubt false color control affects moiré patterns.  If it does, it seems misplaced in the noise reduction section, because moiré is not noise.

Comment: @dpollitt: It was a guess, based on the usual meaning of "false color." I've never used Silkypix. But the truth seems to be that it works on both moire-related false color and color noise: "False Color Control: The software enables to reduce both false colors occur in the fine structure area (high frequency area) and color noise." The combination seems a little idiosyncratic. http://www.isl.co.jp/SILKYPIX/english/products/ds3/manual/man0006.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The False Color Control will **remove the color noise**, while the Noise Reduction Control will **remove the high frequency non-color noise**. These are your two main sliders.  The other two "cancellers" are essentially to **fine tune** and dial back the other two main sliders.