# Is there a name for artifacts for taking a photo of LCD / LED screens and how to remove or avoid it?

Tags: artifacts, moire

The following is a photo of a game console 3DS, although the 3D is turned off:

[image]

There is "fish nest" artifacts, and sometimes the lines even curve on some photos.  iPhotos on a Mac seems to try to minimize its effect, but if the window is being resized, the fish nest can change shape along the way of the resize, and then its effect is minimized once the resizing is done.

Is there a name for such artifacts, and are there ways to avoid it and/or correct it if that's the only photo you have?

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moire-how-can-we-avoid-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect is called Moire. It is caused by the grid pattern of the photosites in your sensor and the grid of pixels in the screen interacting. It happens when the grids do not exactly line up. It can occur with any gird or parallel lines. It is explanined in more depth [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

To reduce this effect try to reduce how much of line the screen is to the sensor.