# What could be causing these lines and distortion?

Tags: sony, artifacts

I have a Sony DSC-W830 as a little budget camera for a trip, and I've had it for about a year now. Lately the images have begun to come out with some odd lines and what I could only describe as "ghosting".

Here's a shot taken in a higher resolution:
[image]

Here's a shot taken in a lower resolution:
[image]

Recording a video doesn't show any issues. My guess is that this is some form of processor issue. Is there anything we can do to salvage this, or should I just replace it?

Comment: Seems like an Anti-aliasing moire effect but not where I would expect one to appear! Reset your camera to factory default and see if the problem goes away, also at full resolution, take a photo of a Net curtain from several angles and light conditions, IE light coming in from different angles ETC. then take some photos of solid objects with no lines, bottles, pens etc, and then have a read of this previous link - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moiré-how-can-we-avoid-it - could also be an issue with moisture.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be something wrong with the sensor, but I think it's not worth it to have it fixed (or even checked out), since it would be cheaper to buy a new one for less than it would cost to fix it.