# How can I fix false rainbow-looking color shades in pictures of fabric?

Tags: product-photography, artifacts, moire

I just took a few pictures and realized they all came out with this "rainbow" looking shades.

How can I fix it in post-processing? See below.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do fashion photographers avoid moire?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76463/how-do-fashion-photographers-avoid-moire)

Comment: Rotate camera while shooting. Try 30°, 45°, and 60° it will disappear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is to go to PS, Image, Adjustments, Tone and Saturation, and work on the colors yellow, blue and purple, and that should be it. The result should be like this.[image]

Comment: That works OK until the moire includes some of the same colors as the item being photographed.

Comment: This 'fixed' image may have gotten rid of the 'rainbow moire', but it has increased the moire in the overall image. It has really just replaced one problem with another.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool in Adobe Camera Raw specifically for [fixing moire](http://scottkelby.com/a-little-known-feature-of-photoshop-and-lightroom-to-the-rescue/).  In case you are not familiar, ACR comes with PS and Lightroom.

Comment: Agreed, a Program specifically designed to fix moire is better than adjusting the colors (which wouldn't work for a single colored mesh). We have a discussion about this Problem on our Site: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moir%C3%A9-how-can-we-avoid-it and the Adobe Site has useful Info also: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1071409 . - You want to zoom in your LCD View when you take the Photo in the first place and reposition yourself or adjust the Focal Length before you take the Photo as truly "fixing" it in Post is difficult (like Photoshopping out an object).