# Why does this ugly line pattern appear when I upload my full-sized image to a website or view on mobile?

Tags: jpeg, artifacts, moire

I have 5760×3840 size JPEG image and when I upload it to a website or try to view on mobile, some kind of line things seem to be going on it. It looks ugly. I tried to resize the image to 1200X800 and it looks fine, but its quality has gone. How to fix these issue without loosing quality?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Moiré pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do fashion photographers avoid moire?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76463/how-do-fashion-photographers-avoid-moire)

Comment: See also: [What is moiré? How can we avoid it?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/11909)

Comment: Related (different process that created the problem, but the explanation and the phenomenon are identical): [What caused this pattern of lines (moire?) in this picture I scanned from a book?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/70139)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moiré effect is due to [spatial frequency folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). If a repetitive pattern (cloth, floor tiles, roof tiles...) in your picture is going to be about 1px after scaling, you get moiré. The best cure is to blur the image **before** scaling it down, to remove those kind of details, which won't be visible in the final image anyway. Roughly, the blur radius should be X pixels if you downscale X times. In the picture below, the moiré on the wall was avoided by blurring.  Notice that this didn't impact the final detail on the statue:

[image: statue moiré]