# Which gear can be used to specifically eliminate moire?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, moire

I currently have a canon 100D (I'm not a photographer - I own a business and do my own product photography because of budget constraints). The moire shows up on solid colour garments.

I have tried everything including zooming in/out, changing the camera angle, focusing somewhere else in the frame, using a large aperture, etc. I have even tried removing it in lightroom, although the artificial colors go away, unfortunately the texture is still affected.

I have heard the 100D has an anti-aliasing filter to prevent moire, so I'm not sure why it is still happening. I wanted to invest in a high resolution camera such as the Nikon 7100D - would it be worth it?

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76463/how-do-fashion-photographers-avoid-moire

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is moiré? How can we avoid it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/what-is-moir%c3%a9-how-can-we-avoid-it)

Comment: You say that you've tried shooting with a large aperture...but in fact using a very small one is a way to mitigate moire. Have you tried using f/16 or f/22 and does this help at all?

Comment: *"If I make the aperture too small, I have to compensate with decreased shutter speed/increased noise as I'm using natural lighting."* I'm confused by this...yes, using f/22 means increasing your shutter speed...but you should still be at the same ISO, so noise levels will not increase. I understand you're using natural light...but you're shooting an inanimate object...shutter speeds up into the seconds should be A-okay, assuming you have a tripod

Comment: @Hueco. I've done moire testing on an 1Ds II and f22 was required obliterate it. About 1/3 of it was still there at f16. Also, long exp. times improved motion blur from camera shutter and mirror slap.

Comment: @doug awesome bit of knowledge. Thanks! And yea, any shutter speed between a second or two and 1/30 usually benefits greatly from the use of mirror lock up followed by a remote release

Comment: Please add a photo that demonstrates what you believe to be moiré.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about product photographs where Moiré patterns show up.  The antialiasing filter of a camera works to suppress such patterns at scale 100% when every pixel the camera has taken shows on the screen.  But it is very unlikely that your catalog images are viewed at 100% of the camera scale.  Instead of letting the web viewer scale down the images, try doing so yourself in image processing software to the size that is going to be used on-screen.  Scaling down usually offers a dropdown menu of "interpolation" options.  (Bi-)cubic interpolation tends to work reasonably well when available.  The strongest Moiré suppression should be available with a "sinc" or "Lanczos" filter, but that may cause some other artifacts, so you should try out the various available options.

Comment: +1 More often than not, moire in low resolution images is more attributable to scaling errors than to aliasing actually captured by the sensor.

Comment: I agree, but rather than scaling and editing to eliminate moire (which can be difficult); it might make more sense to compose the image so that cropping leaves only the required resolution, which can then be used at 100% (i.e. 1024x pixels remaining).

Comment: I've run across moire baked into the image because the anti-aliasing camera filter is not very effective with red or blue textured fabric where only 1/4 of the sensors are most active. Shooting with high f stop is the cure.  OTOH, I've also run across scaling moire that isn't in the image using Photoshop.Converting to a gamma=1 color space in 15+1 bit mode, rescaling, then back to my standard working space almost always fixes the scaling errors. Photoshop rescaling algorithm apparently doesn't correct for gamma.

Comment: Hi, that's quite interesting. I have a photoshop-like software program called GIMP - I'll try scaling the images with bi-cubic interpolation in GIMP to see what happens.